# Automatically trigger a Cloud Build once it is created

Tags: google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I am deploying a series of Cloud Build Triggers through Terraform, but I also want Terraform to trigger once every deployed Cloud Build so that it can do the initial deployment.

The Cloud Build Triggers are used to deploy Cloud Functions (and also Cloud Run and maybe Workflows). We could deploy the functions in the Terraform but we want to keep the command easy to modify so we don't want to duplicate it on both Terraform and the Cloud Build config.

Comment: What is your global pipeline? What is trigger your terraform?

Comment: Hello, my Terraform is triggered by a Cloud Build. On a push on a branch, it does a terraform apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important for the clarity and the evolutivity/maintainability of your pipeline to separate clearly the concern of each step.

- You have a (set of) step to deploy the infrastructure of your project (here, your terraform)
- You have a (set of) step that run process on your project (can be an Ansible script on VM, trigger Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, or a Cloud Build trigger).

I'm pretty sure that you can add this trigger in Terraform, but I strongly don't recommend you to do this.

---

**Edit 1**

I wasn't clear. You have to run your trigger by API after the terraform deployment, in your main pipeline. Then, the subsequent trigger will be done by Push to the Git repository.

Comment: Sorry, I should've precised it in the original post, but the Cloud Build Triggers that are deployed then deploy Cloud Functions. We set it up as Cloud Build Trigger because we want them to be continuously deployed when we push on the repo containing the Cloud Functions. We could deploy the functions using Terraform but we'd lose need to maintain the used command both on the Terraform and in the Cloud Build trigger file of each function. Updated post

Comment: I tried to update. I well understood: You create the trigger with Terraform, and you want to run it once, just after the creation. Then the trigger will be used when you update your git code. Let me know if it clearer. If not, try to share a schema or pieces of code.

Comment: ```You have to run your trigger by API after the terraform deployment, in your main pipeline.```

Could you explain this more or link to further resources? It's unclear what is meant by main pipeline.

Comment: I mean the CI/CD pipeline.You run your terraform to set up the infrastructure, then you can run commands to configure infrastructure (SSH, Ansible, and others)